# How to change colorview when button is pressed? (swift)

Tags: ios, view, swift2, constraints, uicolor

This code has a button when pressed the blue box goes from large to small. How can the code be written so that when the button is pressed it goes from large red box to blue small box? Thanks.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let colorview = UIView()
    var initialc = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        colorview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        colorview.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        self.view.addSubview((colorview))

        let leadingc = colorview.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.leadingAnchor)
        let trailingC = colorview.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.trailingAnchor)
        let topc = colorview.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.topAnchor)
        let bottomc = colorview.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -50)

        initialc.appendContentsOf([leadingc,trailingC,topc,bottomc])
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(initialc)


    }
    @IBAction func changethebleep(sender: AnyObject) {

        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints(initialc)

        let widthc = colorview.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(100)
        let heightc = colorview.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(100)
        let centerxc = colorview.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.centerXAnchor)
        let centeryc = colorview.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.centerYAnchor)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([widthc,heightc,centerxc,centeryc])

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

See if you can work this out for yourself. The viewDidLoad method is setting up the initial settings of your `colorview`.

You have code in `viewDidLoad` that sets the `backgroundColor` property of your `colorview` to blue. It uses the expression `UIColor.blueColor()`.

The equivalent expression for red is `UIColor.redColor()`. See if you can figure out how to change the starting color of your `colorview` to red.

Now, in your `changethebleep` method you have somewhat strange code to alter the constraints of your `colorview`, making it smaller. That works, presumably, so let's leave that alone.

You could simply copy the line from your `viewDidLoad` that sets your colorview.backgroundColor to blue and paste it into your `changethebleep` method.

BTW, method names and variable names should be camelCased in Swift, which means that the first letter should be lower-case, and the beginning of each subsequent word should be capitalized. So `changethebleep` should really be `changeTheBleep` and `colorview` should be `colorView`. That won't change the function of your code but those are strong naming conventions in Swift (and in Objective-C as well.)